# Localhost redirects to live site

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am inheriting an existing project and for some reason whenever I try to run a localhost and debug the code locally it always redirects us to the live site hosted on azure after logging into our Microsoft accounts.

This is happening to three of us so I believe it is not a setting issue.  Has anyone seen any issues like this?  I would be happy to post any code that would be helpful but I have not been able to find anything.

All my Visual Studio setting seem fine and I reset them all to make sure.  All of the azure setting seem fine as well.  Our other application runs perfectly fine on a localhost.

This is super frustrating and it's keeping all of us from working on the app at because we have to publish to check any changes.  Any ideas would help!

Comment: You probably set the redirect URL in the OAuth login to go there.

Comment: @SLaks my webconfig looks almost identical to my working application's webconfig.

Comment: Exactly.  You're probably telling the OAuth login to go to the live site.

Comment: @SLaks even when I change the URIs to localhost it still redirects to the live site

Comment: Check the redirect URL parameter being passed in the login URL. If no redirect URL is specified, check the redirect URL settings in the OAuth configuration (not sure which login providers are you using so you would need to check appropriate applications/websites depending on your login provider).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked **override application root url**? 
In one of projects I faced this, 
Go to **project properties** then click on **Web** then check the **Override Application Root** Url properties. 
[about this property, go through this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983445.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might be looking for this, search for a Web.config file. There should be something like

```
<rules>
 <rule>
  ...
  <action type="Redirect" url="https:www.website.com" ...>
 </rule>
</rules>
```

Just comment it out for debbuging in localhost